# Sending alert messages to multiple whatsapp users using Twilio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I need to send whatsapp messages to multiple phone numbers using node.js.I am using the twilio Api to achieve this.I signed up in twilio,followed the steps and used my mobile number for the sandbox.I used the code in node.js application,it worked with my whatsapp number,but not with other phone numbers.Is there anything to deal with a trail version?? Or Is their any other way to sort this out?  please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [WhatsApp Sandbox](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/sandbox) is intended for testing and you can only send messages to numbers that have sent you the phrase required to join your sandbox (the phrase is the word "join" plus two random words, like "join ceil-maltese").

Once you have tested and you want to take your application to production, you need to [create a WhatsApp Business profile and connect a Twilio number that you own to it](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/connect-number-business-profile). Once you have gone through the [process documented here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/connect-number-business-profile) you will be able to send WhatsApp messages to your users [once they have opted-in to receive those notifications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api#whatsapp-opt-in-requirements).

Comment: Yeah ,I referred this. Is there any other way I can send wp messages to multiple people without verifying  for free?? Something other than twilio also fine.

Comment: There is not, these are WhatsApp's rules.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro ! One more thing ,can we use anyother service for free ?? Like can we send Sms without verifying to multiple users ?If there is anyother platform ,kindly let me know .

Comment: Services for sending messages like this both cost and require verifying for two reasons. Firstly, it costs the service to send the SMS to a carrier, secondly, allowing free, unverified access to sending messages would open a service up to potential abuse and spam. If you want to send messages you are going to need to go through the process of verification and pay for it.